# Android - multithread TCP connection

Tags: java, android, multithreading, tcp, android-asynctask

I've been searching for an answer to my problem, but none of the solutions so far have helped me solve it. I'm working on an app that communicates with another device that works as a server. The app sends queries to the server and receives appropriate responses to dynamically create fragments.

In the first implementation the app sent the query and then waited to receive the answer in a single thread. But that solution wasn't satisfactory since the app did not receive any feedback from the server. The server admin said he was receiving the queries, however he hinted that the device was sending the answer back too fast and that the app probably wasn't already listening by the time the answer arrived.

So what I am trying to achieve is create seperate threads: one for listening and one for sending the query. The one that listens would start before we sent anything to the server, to ensure the app does not miss the server response.

Implementing this so far hasn't been succesful. I've tried writing and running seperate Runnable classes and AsyncTasks, but the listener never received an answer and at some points one of the threads didn't even execute. Here is the code for the asynctask listener:

```
            @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            int bufferLength = 28;
            String masterIP = "192.168.1.100";

            try {
                Log.i("TCPQuery", "Listening for ReActor answers ...");
                Socket tcpSocket = new Socket();
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(masterIP, 50001);
                try {               
                    tcpSocket.connect(socketAddress);
                    Log.i("TCPQuery", "Is socket connected: " + tcpSocket.isConnected());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while(true){

                    Log.i("TCPQuery", "Listening ...");
                    try{
                        Log.i("TCPQuery", "Waiting for ReActor response ...");
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                        tcpSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                        Log.i("TCPQuery", "Received message " + Arrays.toString(buffer) + " from ReActor.");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("TCPQuery", "An error occured receiving the message.");
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "Error", e);
            }

            return "";
        }
```

And this is how the tasks are called:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
          listener.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
          sender.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "");
        }
        else {
          listener.execute();
          sender.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
```

How exactly would you approach this problem? If this code is not sufficient I would be glad to post more.

Comment: I forgot to mention that running a single one of the threads either listener or sender works without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Android's `AsyncTask` is actually only one thread, no matter how many you create, so if you really want 2 threads running at the same time, I suggest you use standard Java concurrent package tools, not `AsyncTask`. As explained [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) **If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent pacakge** such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Comment: I've tried with basic Java Threads as well, but without success. How exactly would you approach the problem by using standard Java Threads? I just created two threads, each with the code to connect to the server and then I called them one after the other, but the result was as described above.

Comment: I have a service (in Android 4.1) with several threads running and they run all fine. In the code above you're not showing how you're sending receiving, only receiving. I don't know the logic of your program, but I suggest one socket for sending and another for receiving (which means having a server-side in your device too).

Comment: I've tried a somewhat similar approach, but I only used a single Socket. Basically the connection is established in a "master" thread and after the socket is up and running I run two seperate threads(that use that socket) the listener and sender respectively. The approach seems to work, however I haven't had the chance to test it with the actual device yet (it works with my own server implementation). If you have any doubts about my solution, I would appreciate additional feedback, but I will indefinitely post more info when I get the chance to test it with the real deal. Thx to all so far!

Comment: The sollution actually proved to be somewhat different than what I thought it would be. The problem was actually not as much in the thread part of the construct as it was in the fact that the device attempted to reconnect back to the app, but the app didn't have a server socket waiting for the connection. A misunderstanding about the mechanics of the "server" device. Thanks to everyone again.

Answer (score 0):

Look this is tcp connection. So you don't need to bother about data lose. This is port to port connection and it never sends end of stream (-1). Perhaps you have to care about read functionality. Because you can not conform all steams are received or not. Tcp read method is a blocking call. If your read buffer size is smaller than available stream size then it block until it can read fully. And you are using android device, perhaps available stream can vary depending upon your device network. So you have 2 options,
1) your buffer size should be dynamic. At first check your available input stream size by using is.available() and create your buf size by this size. If available size is zero then sleep for a certain time to check it is lost its stream availability or not.
2) set your input stream timeout. It really works, because it reads its available stream and wait for the timeout delay, if any stream is not available within the timeout period then it throws timeout exception.
Try to change your code.

Comment: *"available stream can vary depending upon your device network"* I don't think this is correct, how can data vary depending on the network? Makes no sense to me. Network has nothing to do with device type, it's the same for phone than for PC.

Comment: Look, suppose your total stream strength 500. The available stream never sends equal length. It may return 50, 100, 30 some time 0 and so on. So that if you receive 0 then you have to wait for a while and set read timeout to check further availability. If no stream is available then it will automatically throws readtimeout exception. I faced this problem before and I handled this problem by this mechanism. Try this, your problem will must be resolved.

Comment: First I'm not the one asking, and second I've never had that problem. If you send 500 bytes, you will receive 500 bytes, no matter what the source/destination device is, unless of course network goes down, in which case you will receive an exception of course.